# Prisma with Next-Auth, user creation fails cause of Keycloak's api response key name

Tags: javascript, keycloak, prisma, next-auth

I'm using next-auth's keycloak adapter with the default settings to save, keycloak's repsonse to a database using Prisma orm.

The problem is that keycloak's response (which is the account variable in next-auth) has a key-value field ***not-before-policy***.

```
  data: {
    provider: 'keycloak',
    type: 'oauth',
    providerAccountId: '', 
    access_token: '..--P0Y19Ee-TKh47w',      
       expires_at: 1636469568,
    refresh_expires_in: 1800,
    refresh_token: 'fasdfsf',
    token_type: 'Bearer',
    id_token: 'fsdfA8HL85zFsekhgp1F0g',
    'not-before-policy': 1636367915, <-----------------------------------------------------
    session_state: 'b11fe259-961f-49c3-b1b6-27ff8b22d94c',     
    scope: 'openid email profile',
    userId: 'ckvs7jszn0006qck9qnajrqan'
  }
```

The character ***"-"*** (dash) is preventing me of define on Prisma schema the field in the Account model.

```
not-before-policy Int
```

According to [this issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1139) on *Github* and [this topic](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/upgrade-guides/upgrading-versions/upgrading-to-prisma-3/named-constraints) in *documentation* this issue has been resolved.

I am trying to map this value (with the 'illegal' characters) by doing something like this in the account model.

```
  not_before_policy Int     @map("not-before-policy") // THIS doesn't work!
```

This also doesn't work and gives me errors:

```
 1
 17 updateUser: (data) => p.user.update({ where: { id: data.id }, data }),
 18 deleteUser: (id) => p.user.delete({ where: { id } }),
→ 19 linkAccount: (data) => p.account.create({
  data: {
    provider: 'keycloak',
    type: 'oauth',
    providerAccountId: '', 
    access_token: '..--P0Y19Ee-TKh47w',      
       expires_at: 1636469568,
    refresh_expires_in: 1800,
    refresh_token: 'fasdfsf',
    token_type: 'Bearer',
    id_token: 'fsdfA8HL85zFsekhgp1F0g',
    'not-before-policy': 1636367915, 
    session_state: 'b11fe259-961f-49c3-b1b6-27ff8b22d94c',     
    scope: 'openid email profile',
    userId: 'ckvs7jszn0006qck9qnajrqan'
  }
})

Unknown arg not-before-policy in data.not-before-policy for type AccountUncheckedCreateInput. Did you mean not_before_policy? Available args:
type AccountUncheckedCreateInput {
 id?: String
 userId: String
 type: String
 not_before_policy?: Int | Null
 provider: String
 providerAccountId: String
 refresh_token?: String | Null
 access_token?: String | Null
 expires_at?: Int | Null
 token_type?: String | Null
 scope?: String | Null
 id_token?: String | Null
 session_state?: String | Null
 oauth_token_secret?: String | Null
 oauth_token?: String | Null
 refresh_expires_in?: Int | Null
}
```

Can I make prisma somehow understand the keycloak's response with this 'illegal' name or could i mutate next-auth's object which has the keycloak's response before it will be called by the next-auth-prisma-adapter ?
Do I miss something from the docs?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You should be using `not_before_policy` in your `account.create` call for it to work. Also, could you not just manually reassign/map the `not-before-policy` field from the object returned from keycloak to the `not_before_policy` field when writing data to Prisma?

Comment: Next-auth has an adapter for Prisma, which automatically calls account.create with the keycloak's response (on login) _account_  when writing data to prisma. It's not me who will decide what the data will be in the account.create(data) or when the function will be called. So, of course, If i could intervene on this function call there would be no problem.
So I am asking if there is a work around to manually change the params of account.create or if i could define the prisma schema differently so it will understand not-before-policy

Comment: I understand now. Unfortunately, there's no way to have fields in your prisma client with "-" in the name.  The ` @map` annotation in your schema allows you to introspect/create database columns with "-" inside the name, but the field name generated in the Prisma client can not have "-". Perhaps it's worth opening an issue about this in the next-auth repo?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will open a new issue and if there will be a fix, I will update the question.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help further. Best of luck with this!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of how to override PrismaAdapter's `linkAccount` method to ignore the Keycloak-specific attributes `not-before-policy` and `refresh_expires_in`:

```js
const adapter = PrismaAdapter(prisma);
const _linkAccount = adapter.linkAccount;
adapter.linkAccount = (account) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  const { 'not-before-policy': _, refresh_expires_in, ...data } = account;
  return _linkAccount(data);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Keycloak is sending extra fields which default Prisma Schema doesn't know about. You can check out [this](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/3067) similiar conversation from next-auth's github issues page.

But in a nutshell you may override linkAccount in adapter callbacks or alter the default Prisma Schema to include those extra fields.